# How can i give perfect relationship each other table?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am confuse about database relationship...I am creating website like classified ads..without registartion how user can post??
Registration users and without registration users form are same...but how to store data without registartion user

[This is form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9W2j.png)

[This is database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeWTo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.id` is required on your `Advertise` table only. So, what you can do is first set the `user_id` on `Advertise` table that way you can have advertises from registered users and non users. 
So if a particular user can check his ads then he can check his ads.
About the unauthenticated users they wont have the deligacy of viewing their ads. 
Or you can do something like :
Check `auth()->check()` if auth exists then give that form if doesn't then get the unregistered user `email` and give the services of checking ads with `email`

Comment: You are right...I used user_id field in Advertise Table....When i fill the form and submit all data store in database but user_id field is empty

Comment: yes it will be empty because there are no user authenticated.. so instead make it `nullable` in database..

Comment: I used nullable

Comment: I used this  $user_id = Auth::user();
         $user_id->post()->create($request->all()); nd store user_id in table -